# How can I disable the scroll-to-end feature

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

Whenever I run my code in Pycharm (community version), the run window automatically scrolls to the end. I would like to turn this feature off. However, everytime I run my code it re-enables itself.

I've looked for answers. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529137/is-there-a-console-scroll-lock-in-intellij/44732992#44732992) on stackoverflow, suggests clicking in the run panel before it ends. My code, however, is finished before i can click in the panel to disable the scrolling.

Also under settings I cannot find any options to disable this.